# Trying to do insert select with groovy and running into exception

Tags: java, sql, groovy

We are trying to write groovy test where we want to duplicate existing record with some of the values changed. Below is the sql. We are passing list with 3 values.

```
insert into tableA (col1,col2, col3, col4)
select ?, col2, col3, ? from tableA where col2=?
```

It is throwing exception when we try to execute as the set parameters are not mapped for '?' in 'select' clause. I vaguely remember I have faced same issue in past while doing plain jdbc.

We are using informix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using groovy.sql.Sql you can do the following:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

Sql db
try {
    // other methods of obtaining Sql exist but we'll use...
    db = Sql.newInstance( 'url', 'user', 'pwd', 'yourDriver' )
    db.executeUpdate( 'insert into tableA (col1,col2, col3, col4) select ?,  col2, col3, ? from tableA where col2 = ?', ['bind1', 'bind2', 'bind3'] )
}
finally {
    db?.close()
}
```

Comment: We are using db.execute.. replaced with executeUpdate. Still we got same error.

Comment: The above works using Oracle, what DB are you using?

Comment: we are using informix